# Python: How to remove a row?

Tags: python, database, twitter

Within the function, ToDataFrame, within the second For Loop, I would like to remove all Rows in which the tweet.user.description contains the keyword "Solutions". At the moment, I am detecting this and appending it within a list.

I have attempted to use "Dataset.drop()", "Dataset.remove()", also "tweets.description.remove()", etc. None of these seem to work.

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import sys
import time


def toDataFrame(tweets):
    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()
    DataSet['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['twitterlink'] = ['https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/'+str(tweet.id) for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetText'] = [tweet.text.encode('UTF-8') for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetRetweetCt'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetCreated'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userLocation'] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userTimezone'] = [tweet.user.time_zone for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Coordinates'] = [tweet.coordinates for tweet in tweets] #Nullable. Represents the geographic location of this Tweet as reported by the user or client application.
    DataSet['Place'] = [tweet.place for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['GeoEnabled'] = [tweet.user.geo_enabled for tweet in tweets] #must be TRUE for user to attach geo data 
    tweets_place= []
    #users_retweeted = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        if tweet.place:
            tweets_place.append(tweet.place.full_name)
        else:
            tweets_place.append('null')
    DataSet['TweetPlace'] = [i for i in tweets_place]

    tweets_description= []
    for tweet in tweets:
        if "Solutions" in tweet.user.description:
            tweets_description.append(tweet.user.description) 
        else:
            tweets_description.append('null')
    DataSet['TweetDescription'] = [i for i in tweets_description]
    return DataSet

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret,'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
#auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
if (not api):
    print ("Failed")
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    print ("Collecting..") # Enter lat and long and radius in Kms  q='ganesh'
    search_words = “travel”
    new_search = search_words + " -filter:retweets" + "-is:retweet"
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, tweet_mode='Extended', q=new_search,geocode="38.0400,-122.7400,50km",since='2017-09-01',until='2021-09-05',lang='en',count=100, exclude_replies=True)
    results=[]
    for item in cursor.items(5): # quantity
         results.append(item)


    DataSet = toDataFrame(results)

    DataSet.to_csv('icreatedthis.csv',index=False)
    print ("Complete")

'''

appreciate any help
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .loc function.

You dont want rows that contains 'Solutions' string, so it would look something like this to remove them (Notice the '~' symbol):

```
DataSet = DataSet.loc[~DataSet["description"].str.contains("Solutions")]
```

Comment: Hi I ended up getting a keyerror when attempting to do this.  raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'description'

Comment: Append all descriptions in your dataset (Without using of the second for loop) and then , try to run the .loc function over it
--
Replace 'description' with the name of the column you are trying to evaluate (The one that contains the description texts).